# Do we really need this verification for in-app over iOS 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase

Back last year, that russian hacker created a way to validate in-app purchases without payment and [this guy created a class to verify each purchase](https://github.com/evands/iap_validation).

As far as I know, this technique exposed by the hacker does not work on iOS 6 anymore, but I am not sure about that.

I am creating a new app for iOS 6 and trying to minimize the code to a minimum and even better than that, my in-apps involved hosted content with Apple, so I wonder if this added validation is really necessary for my case.

Remember that

1. I am developing for iOS 6 and up;
2. my in-apps have hosted content with apple, so even if the hacking technique works the person will never get the content hosted with apple.

any thoughts?

thanks.

Comment: *It is really pleasing to watch that sometimes questions also provides interesting information rahter than Answersand which forces me to bookmark it.*

Comment: what information did you find interesting? 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vulnerability should be addressed in iOS6, but that does not mean you should deviate from Receipt Validation best practices in general. See [Verifying Store Receipts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html) and 
[In-App Purchase Receipt Validation on iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012484) for more information.

As mentioned in the links above, Apple recommend you follow their best practices for receipt validation, be it on iOS 5 or iOS 6. "Simplicity of code" is not a good enough excuse to deviate from these guidelines. If you structure your code into well defined classes, you can abstract away all the receipt validation logic to its own class, making the code that uses it a lot cleaner anyway.

If you connect to the App Store directly from the App for validation, the measures they explicitly state (see ["My app performs validation by connecting to the App Store server directly. How am I affected?"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012484-CH0-SW5)) should help. If you implement them in an abstracted way (in a category or class), then it should still keep your code clean.

Even if your content is hosted by Apple, you're still giving yourself an extra safeguard against fraud. Apple are not perfect; they could slip up themselves leaving your app open.

Ultimately, **when you're dealing with your own revenue, you better play it safe than be sorry afterwards.**